# How can I print vertically a 2d array with different row length in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I know how to print vertically a 2d array when all the rows have the same length but what happens when an array is like this:

```
{{2,3,4}, {6,23,56,78}, {12,11,43,54,77}};
```

How I am supposed to loop through the vertical values?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each column will tell you the length of the array.  Use that array length as the to test to see if the column has a value for that.  If so, print it, otherwise print a blank.

```
int[][] matrix;   //column, then row
for (int row=0; row<maxRows; row++) {
    for (int col=0; col<maxCol; i++) {
        int[] column = matrix[col];
        if (row < column .length) {
            print(column[row]);
        }
        else {
            print(a blank);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will that print a 2D array vertically ?

Comment: OK, missed that it is printed inverted.  Instead, you test to see fi the current column has enough value to reach the current row.  If so, print it, otherwise print a blank.